# How to sort this array of objects, since it has x and y coordinates in JS?

Tags: javascript, sorting

I can't sort my array of objects "datoa" so that if I sort x values, corresponding y values change too.

The variable myJSON is structured like:

```
var myJSON = [
  {
    "": 0,
    "Comune": "BONDENO",
    "PUNTEGGIOSCUOLA1516": 4.25,
    "Value 1": 63,
    "Value 2": 8,
    "Value 3": 17,
    "DANNO": 6,
    "Somma valori": 88,
    "numero_di_scuole": 4,

  },
  {
    "": 1,
    "Comune": "CAVEZZO",
    "PUNTEGGIOSCUOLA1516": 3.75,
    "Value 1": 23,
    "Value 2": 2,
    "Value 3": 9,
    "DANNO": 8,
    "Somma valori": 34,
    "numero_di_scuole": 4,

  }, etc.
```

The code to make some values into coordinates is:

```
const xData= myJSON.map(itm=>(itm['Value 1']+itm['Value 2'])/itm['numero_di_scuole']);

const yData = myJSON.map(itm=>itm['PUNTEGGIOSCUOLA1516']);


const datoa = xData.map((x, i) => {
  return {
    x: x,
    y: yData[i]
  };
});
```

However, if I do sort like:

```
datoa.sort(function(a,b) {
    if( a.x == b.x) return a.y-b.y;
    return a.x-b.x;
});
```

My goal is that if I have `datoa = [{x: 11, y:2}, {x:5, y:6}]`
with sorting datoa becomes `datoa = [{x: 5, y:6}, {x:11, y:2}]`
It won't work. How can I do it?

Comment: please add the wanted result. please add more data as well.

Comment: The name of the variable `myJSON` is misleading (wrong) because its content is _not_ [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) but an array of objects.

Comment: I should have added more details!

Comment: `[{x: 11, y:2}, {x:5, y:6}].sort(function(a,b) { if( a.x == b.x) { return a.y-b.y; } return a.x-b.x; });` results in the expected order of the elements. Please add a [mcve] that shows the actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could sort by the "*square root of the sum of squares*" with [`Math.hypot`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/hypot), which moves smaller `x` and `y` elements to top.

```js
var data = [{ "": 0, Comune: "BONDENO", PUNTEGGIOSCUOLA1516: 4.25, "Value 1": 63, "Value 2": 8, "Value 3": 17, DANNO: 6, "Somma valori": 88, numero_di_scuole: 4 }, { "": 1, Comune: "CAVEZZO", PUNTEGGIOSCUOLA1516: 3.75, "Value 1": 23, "Value 2": 2, "Value 3": 9, DANNO: 8, "Somma valori": 34, numero_di_scuole: 4 }],
    datoa = data.map(itm => ({
        x: (itm['Value 1'] + itm['Value 2']) / itm['numero_di_scuole'],
        y: itm.PUNTEGGIOSCUOLA1516
    }));

datoa.sort((a, b) => Math.hypot(a.x, a.y) - Math.hypot(b.x, b.y));

console.log(datoa);
```

Comment: The [sorting works](https://jsfiddle.net/t7u2h4c5/). Why should Anna change anything?

Comment: maybe op wants a different sorting and respect smaller values for `y` as well ...?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is in the syntax `if` statement of your `sort` function. Add curly braces `{}` around your first return statement, and it should work.

```
datoa.sort(function(a, b) {
    if(a.x == b.x) {
        return a.y - b.y
    }
    return a.x - b.x;
})
```

Alternately, you could use a ternary function to clean it up just a bit:

```
datoa.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.x == b.x ? a.y - b.y : a.x - b.x;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need a single map over the source data, then the sort can keep everything together:

```
const datoa = myJSON
    .map(itm => ({
        x: (itm['Value 1'] + itm['Value 2']) / itm['numero_di_scuole'],
        y: itm['PUNTEGGIOSCUOLA1516']
    }))
    .sort((a, b) => (a.x === b.x) ? a.y - b.y : a.x - b.x));
```